# copying oracle to sqlserver 2005 jdbc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, jdbc

Is there any way of copying a database from oracle to sqlserver 2005? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate from Oracle to SQL Server with Microsoft's [SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx). It is available both to SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

If you have lots of (complicated) stored procedures and such, the migration might get a bit tedious. I have only experience with databases with simple procedures and could just rewrite them and do the data copy to empty tables in SQL Server with the import functionality using Oracle connector (usable from SQL Server if you have installed Oracle client tools to the SQL Server machine). This way I didn't even need to use the Migration Assistant tool.